# Pyramid + FormAlchemy model improvement

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid, formalchemy

I currently have two separate models (shown below), which works fine for my application in small scale/testing. However when there are over 5000 customers searching via a FK dropdown box will be tiresome each time a note is inputted.

My question is, is there anyway I could put the Note model inside of my Customer model? So that from inside my Customer model I could add notes directly?

```
#models.py
samples_to_customer = Table('samples_to_customer', Base.metadata,
  Column('customer_id', Integer, ForeignKey('customer.id')),
  Column('sample_id', Integer, ForeignKey('samples.id'))
  )

#Create a cusotmer model to store customer numbers

class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'customer'
    __acl__ = [
            (Allow, 'admin', ALL_PERMISSIONS),
            (Allow, 'saff', ('view', 'edit')),
        ]
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode, unique=True) #this will be the variable used to search the existing db
    customer_samples = relationship('Sample', secondary='samples_to_customer', backref='samples')
    sales_rep = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('rep.id'))
    rep = relationship('Rep', backref='rep')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

# This model will have its own entry view/page a user logs on and enters notes (according to a customer
# number) they then get stored/saved onto the Customers account
class Note(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'note'
    __acl__ = [
            (Allow, 'admin', ALL_PERMISSIONS),
            (Allow, 'staff', ('view', 'edit')),
        ]    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode)
    pub_date = Column(Date)
    customer_no = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('customer.id'))
    customer = relationship('Customer', backref='notes')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 1):

I didnt find anyway todo this.

But I am still very new to pyramid and formalchemy.

I have decided to write my own admin/model interface which let me do what I needed to with pyramid views and jinja2 templates. Without using formalchemy and or javascript.

I am coming from django so didnt realise just how easy it was to write my own model admin views and templates.